# Distinction between 2 NETTypeInfo answers

Tags: functions

In a NETLink application I checked all the types offered by  `LoadedNETTypes[]` according to the following:

```
tt1 = NETTypeInfo["Wolfram.NETLink.DynamicDLLNamespace.DLLWrapper1",   "Methods", "DRV_AOVoltageOut"]

tt2 = NETTypeInfo["Wolfram.NETLink.DynamicDLLNamespace.DLLWrapper2",   "Methods", "DRV_AOVoltageOut"]
```

`tt1` offer `Null` response but `tt2` offer the non-null response below:

•   Methods (matching string pattern DRV_AOVoltageOut)
static short DRV_AOVoltageOut(int DriverHandle, Wolfram.NETLink.DynamicDLLNamespace.DLLWrapper2+PT_AOVoltageOut IntPtr)

My question is how to distinct between tt1 and tt2, because I obtain tt1==tt2 although they are obviously different?